How do you properly implement Snap To Grid Logic for a QGraphicsItem? Mine is not working
I am working on a project that requires me to create a custom QGraphicsItemGroup that snaps to a grid when a widget is checked. The snap to grid logic works (partially) as when I move the item, it moves 10 pixels per move (snapping). However, it moves from 0, 0 in the scene, meaning if the group is created at 100, 100, it will move as if it where created at 0, 0. I don't know if I really explained the problem well, so feel free to play with it yourself.
class CustomGraphicsItemGroup(QGraphicsItemGroup):
    def __init__(self, widget):
        super().__init__()

        self.widgets = widget

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):
        # Call the parent class paint method first
        super().paint(painter, option, widget)

        # If the item is selected, draw a custom selection highlight
        if option.state & QStyle.State_Selected:
            pen = painter.pen()
            pen.setColor(QColor('#e00202'))
            pen.setWidth(2)
            pen.setCapStyle(Qt.RoundCap)
            painter.setPen(pen)
            painter.drawRect(self.boundingRect())

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event: QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent):
        if self.widgets.isChecked():
            block_size = 10

            # Calculate the position relative to the scene's coordinate system
            scene_pos = event.scenePos()
            x = int(scene_pos.x() / block_size) * block_size
            y = int(scene_pos.y() / block_size) * block_size

            # Set the position relative to the scene's coordinate system
            self.setPos(x, y)
            
        else:
            # Call the superclass's mouseMoveEvent to move the item as normal
            super().mouseMoveEvent(event)

I tried using different numbers, division, multiplication, and nothing worked. Any help or code snippits are appreciated.

So first off all, when inheriting the QGraphicsItemGroup, one should consider the concepts of it. The group does not want to have a child in the constructor. Instead, items are added to the group. The group itself is then a proxy for all added items.
There are two ways to create a group in the scene. The option with which custom groups can be created in the scene is as follows.

Create a group and add it to the scene.

group = CustomGraphicsItemGroup()
group.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIsSelectable, True)
group.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIsMovable, True)
scene.addItem(group)


Assign items to the group.

group.addToGroup(red_item)
group.addToGroup(blue_item)

You should always use the tools that are available to Qt and not reinvent the wheel. It is important to set the right flags so that an item (or a group) is selectable and movable. Then use the self.isSelected of the item itself.
To your question, an offset for the mouse must be applied somehow so that no sudden jumps occur. This can be stored in the mousePressEvent.
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import QRect, QPoint
from PySide6.QtGui import QColor, Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QGraphicsItemGroup,
    QStyle,
    QGraphicsItem,
    QGraphicsScene,
    QGraphicsView,
    QApplication,
    QGraphicsRectItem,
)


class CustomGraphicsItemGroup(QGraphicsItemGroup):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.mouse_offset = QPoint(0, 0)
        self.block_size = 10

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):
        # Call the parent class paint method first
        super().paint(painter, option, widget)

        # If the item is selected, draw a custom selection highlight
        if option.state & QStyle.State_Selected:
            pen = painter.pen()
            pen.setColor(QColor("#e00202"))
            pen.setWidth(2)
            pen.setCapStyle(Qt.RoundCap)
            painter.setPen(pen)
            painter.drawRect(self.boundingRect())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton:
            self.mouse_offset = event.pos()
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.isSelected():
            # Calculate the position relative to the scene's coordinate system
            scene_pos = event.scenePos()
            x = (
                int(scene_pos.x() / self.block_size) * self.block_size
                - self.mouse_offset.x()
            )
            y = (
                int(scene_pos.y() / self.block_size) * self.block_size
                - self.mouse_offset.y()
            )

            # Set the position relative to the scene's coordinate system
            self.setPos(x, y)
        else:
            # Call the superclass's mouseMoveEvent to move the item as normal
            super().mouseMoveEvent(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    scene = QGraphicsScene()
    view = QGraphicsView(scene)
    scene.setSceneRect(QRect(0, 0, 500, 500))
    view.setFixedWidth(500)
    view.setFixedHeight(500)
    view.show()

    group = CustomGraphicsItemGroup()
    group.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIsSelectable, True)
    group.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIsMovable, True)
    scene.addItem(group)
    red_item = QGraphicsRectItem()
    red_item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIsSelectable, True)
    red_item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIsMovable, True)
    red_item.setBrush(QColor("red"))
    red_item.setRect(0, 0, 80, 80)
    red_item.setPos(150, 150)
    group.addToGroup(red_item)

    blue_item = QGraphicsRectItem()
    blue_item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIsSelectable, True)
    blue_item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIsMovable, True)
    blue_item.setBrush(QColor("blue"))
    blue_item.setRect(0, 0, 100, 100)
    blue_item.setPos(100, 100)
    group.addToGroup(blue_item)

    scene.addItem(blue_item)
    scene.addItem(red_item)
    sys.exit(app.exec())



This works flawlessy. This achieves the exact effect I was going for. Thank you so much. I do have a quick question though, why do you use "group.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIsSelectable, True)" instead of "group.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)"

Its just the enum class for the flags. Maybe its different on PyQt or your system. At least my IDE can't find the reference otherwise.
When you're happy with my answer, consider setting it as "Accepted answer" :)

@KellerHydle Since PyQt6 all enums require their own namespace (they are now actual Python enums), and this change has been introduced in the latest PyQt5 as well, even if the old behavior is still valid.

The most appropriate way to limit positions of a graphics item is to work with itemChange().
By setting the ItemSendsGeometryChanges flag, we can check for ItemPositionChange changes and eventually alter the value before returning.
This makes it possible to completely avoid overriding mouseMoveEvent(), which may become inconsistent under certain circumstances, and it's better to leave the mouse movement handling to the graphics view.
As noted in the other answer, your problem was that you were considering the scene position without the offset of the initial position of the mouse relative to the item. This is one of the drawbacks of trying to implement movement on your own, and that's why it's always preferable to let Qt do it.
Note that making the widget an attribute of the item is not very appropriate. A more correct solution is to connect a signal of the widget to a function of the item that eventually sets the internal state accordingly.
class CustomGraphicsItemGroup(QGraphicsItemGroup):
    _snap = False
    _snapSize = 10
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFlags(
            self.ItemIsMovable
            | self.ItemIsSelectable
            | self.ItemSendsGeometryChanges
        )

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change == self.ItemPositionChange and self._snap:
            value.setX(round(value.x() / self._snapSize) * self._snapSize)
            value.setY(round(value.y() / self._snapSize) * self._snapSize)
        return super().itemChange(change, value)

    def setSnap(self, snap):
        self._snap = snap

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):
        # Call the parent class paint method first
        super().paint(painter, option, widget)

        # If the item is selected, draw a custom selection highlight
        if option.state & QStyle.State_Selected:
            pen = painter.pen()
            pen.setColor(QColor('#e00202'))
            pen.setWidth(2)
            pen.setCapStyle(Qt.RoundCap)
            painter.setPen(pen)
            painter.drawRect(self.boundingRect())


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

scene = QGraphicsScene()
group = CustomGraphicsItemGroup()
group.addToGroup(scene.addRect(0, 0, 30, 30))
group.addToGroup(scene.addRect(100, 50, 20, 30))
scene.addItem(group)
view = QGraphicsView(scene)

snapChk = QCheckBox('Snap')
snapChk.toggled.connect(group.setSnap)

win = QWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout(win)
layout.addWidget(snapChk)
layout.addWidget(view)
win.resize(640, 480)
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())

The usage of round() instead of int() is also more appropriate, since int() always floors the value: for instance, with a grid size of 10, 29.999 will always result in 20 even if it's much closer to 30. With round(), anything above 25.0 will be 30 instead, making mouse movement and snapping more consistent.
